# Objective C Singleton - Prevent Allocating Memeory More than Once

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I use a sinlgeton in my application for managing data that is available to the whole application, which accessed via:

```
static MMProductManager *sharedInstance = nil;
+(MMProductManager*)SharedInstance {
    dispatch_once( &resultsToken, ^(void) {
        if ( ! sharedInstance ) {
            sharedInstance = [[MMProductManager alloc] init];
        }
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Everything is working as expected.

In Objective C, there does not seem to be a way to hide any object's `init` method, and in my case having more than instance of `MMProductManager` would lead to data being duplicated (in the best case scenario).

What I would like to do is guard against instantiating more than one instance. Other languages seem to have this feature; i.e. marking certain methods/classes as private. I am thinking of implementing something along like:

```
-(id)init {
    // guard against instantiating a more than one instance
    if ( sharedInstance )
        return sharedInstance;

    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        self->_resultsQueue = dispatch_queue_create( kMMResultQLAbel, NULL );
        self->_initialized  = FALSE;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
                                                   object:0];

        [self initialize];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Does this approach seem reasonable?

What would happen in the case of someone allocating this class, then calling the `init` described above? Would it be reasonable to override `+(id)alloc`? If so How would I go about doing that?

I know the convention of exposing a `SharedInstance` method is an implicit message to other developers to go through this method, but I would like a bit more control if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to override `- init` (if not for some other reason) - `- init` is **not** the method that creates the instance. You want to override `+ alloc` for this:

```
@implementation SingletonClass

+ (id)alloc
{
    static id instance = nil;
    if (instance == nil) {
        instance = [super alloc];
    }
    return instance;
}

@end
```

This way you can **actually prevent (almost) completely** creating multiple instances of `SingletonClass`.

(Unless somebody falls back to calling

```
id trickyDifferentInstance = class_createInstance(objc_getClass("SingletonClass"), 0));
```

but that's very unlikely.)

Comment: With that I would put all my other initialization in a private category method, and override `init` to return `nil`?

Comment: I doubt very much anyone in my office is going to be calling run time functions explicitly.

Comment: @MikeD No. You would implement `init` just as normally.